# Django 1.8 How do I add `sensitive_variables` or `sensitive_post_parameters` to a FormView method?

Tags: python, django

When debugging an error with a form submit in Django, I noticed that the user's password is in plain view in the debug "Request information" readout as part of the POST parameters.

How do I wrap the `form_valid` (or maybe `dispatch`?) so that `POST['password']` is hidden from the debugging information? I can't seem to find the right combination of `@method_decorator` etc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_variables, sensitive_post_parameters

class ActivateView(FormView):

    form_class = ActivatePasswordForm
    template_name = 'activate.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        # erroneous function which has been fixed
        do_something(form.cleaned_data['password'])

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I have tried:

```
    @method_decorator(sensitive_variables)
    def form_valid(self, form):
```

and:

```
    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters)
    def form_valid(self, form):
```

but both bail out at:

```
Traceback:
File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /activate/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and I've tried:

```
@method_decorator(sensitive_variables)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

and:

```
@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

but both bail out at:

```
Traceback:
File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /activate/
Exception Value: decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique_id'
```

This is the type error mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

### Solved

Solution is a mixture of the two answers below from Dave and Alasdair. Thanks.

The `@sensitive_post_parameters` decorator will only take effect when `DEBUG=False`, which explains why I wasn't seeing anything change. Also, the method has to be called within the `@method_decorator`. So the correct code is:

```
@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password', 'password_again'))
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sensitive_variables` is documented as a decorator rather than an argument to a decorator.  And even with the correct syntax, it's possible but unlikely that "treated in a special way" means that the variables will not be visible in debugging information.

Production servers should never be run with DEBUG=True, and sensitive variables should never appear in any logs generated by a production server.  But when debugging, the goal is to have all the information necessary to track down problems, which includes passwords.  Let us know if the debug page generator censors sensitive variables.  That would be a surprise.

```
def sensitive_variables(*variables):
"""
Indicates which variables used in the decorated function are sensitive, so
that those variables can later be treated in a special way, for example
by hiding them when logging unhandled exceptions.

Two forms are accepted:

* with specified variable names:

    @sensitive_variables('user', 'password', 'credit_card')
    def my_function(user):
        password = user.pass_word
        credit_card = user.credit_card_number
        ...

* without any specified variable names, in which case it is assumed that
  all variables are considered sensitive:

    @sensitive_variables()
    def my_function()
        ...
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have forgotten to call the methods. Try the following:

```
@method_decorator(sensitive_variables())
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Tried this and I'm still seeing the POST variables.

Comment: As @Dave says in his answer, the decorators are meant for when `DEBUG = False`, they don't affect the yellow error pages when `DEBUG = True`.